# If a continuous function is differentiable at a point, is it differentiable in some neighborhood around that point?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, gm.general-mathematics

This seems like it should be true but I was wondering if anyone could prove it. Thanks!

Comment: Start with a continuous nowhere-differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ and multiply by $x^2$. Now it's differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is negative. Take a [bounded nowhere differentiable continuous map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and consider the map $g(x) = f(x) \cdot x^2$, which is differentiable at $x = 0$, but not anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks! I have one more question, how about Lipschitz continuous function which is differentiable almost everywhere? If a Lipschitz continuous function is differentiable at a point, is it differentiable in some neighborhood around that point?

Comment: I think these questions are better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @li ang Duan: *If a Lipschitz continuous function is differentiable at a point, is it differentiable in some neighborhood around that point?* --- A result Zahorski published in 1946 takes care of this and most any related question. The result, along with some very strong specific examples, is given in [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2747372/13130). See also [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-34/issue-1/A-Simple-Proof-of-Zahorskis-Description-of-Non-Differentiability-Sets/rae/1242738925.full).